# How can I return a List<string> from a console application?

Tags: c#, console-application, program-entry-point

I am calling a console application from a Windows forms application. I want to get a list of strings back from the console application.
This is my simplified code...

```
[STAThread]
static List<string> Main(string[] args)
{      
    List<string> returnValues = new List<string>();
    returnValues.Add("str_1");
    returnValues.Add("str_2");
    returnValues.Add("str_3");

    return returnValues;
}
```

Comment: You can only return a void or an int in the main method:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fwzzxz2.aspx

You need to find a different way of storing it somewhere.

The int is a success code of how the program ran, zero means success and others are error messages

Comment: Simply put, the return value of a program isn't meant as program output; it is the program's exit status. It is simply meant to indicate if an error occurred during the program run, and the returned number can be used to specifically indicates _which_ error. To compare, this is the difference between a web request's webpage output, and its returned http status. You're basically trying to make your http request return a web page _as_ http status.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this way you cannot. Main can return only void or int. 
But you can send list to standard output and read it in another app.

In console app add this:

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(returnValues));
```

And in caller app:

```
Process yourApp= new Process();
yourApp.StartInfo.FileName = "exe file";
yourApp.StartInfo.Arguments = "params";
yourApp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
yourApp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
yourApp.Start();    

string output = yourApp.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
List<string> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(output);

yourApp.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't just return a list, you have to serialize it in a way the other end can pick it up.

One option would be to serialize the list to JSON and send it over the `Console.Out` stream. Then, on the other end, read from the process' output stream and deserialize it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot return a string or list of string. The Main method can only return `void` or `int`

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fwzzxz2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Return type for Main methods is either void or int.

Answer (score 0):

Main method is not made for this. But if you want to print your list here is the code :

```
    public void showList(List<String> list)
    {
        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```